# Does Mapbox host the mapbox-gl-opacity plugin?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm looking at the mapbox-gl-opacity plugin, but would like to implement this similarly to the Mapbox example for the mapbox-gl-compare plugin, by using an inline script include such as this:

```
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-compare/v0.4.0/mapbox-gl-compare.js"></script>
```

Is the mapbox-gl-opacity plugin hosted in such a way? If so, what is the URL?

Answer (score 1):

The [mapbox-gl-compare](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-compare) plugin is developed by Mapbox, whereas [mapbox-gl-opacity](https://github.com/dayjournal/mapbox-gl-opacity) is community-maintained (since the repository is not under the Mapbox GitHub organization). So, Mapbox does not host the mapbox-gl-opacity plugin. Rather than using an inline script, you can either follow the [example](https://github.com/dayjournal/mapbox-gl-opacity#example) in the plugin's README, or use the corresponding npm package as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/dayjournal/mapbox-gl-opacity#example---npm).